# How can I jump to a particular class with JavaScript in Bootstrap navbar when scrolling?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want a particular class to jump between my bootstrap navbar using Javascript to highlight the current sections and pages in it. My goal is to highlight current sections and pages that the user is navigating when the user is *scrolling through them*.

As you can see in my below code I have 2 dropdown menus i.e *Homepages section* & *Subpages link* with nav-links in them so I need the dropdown menu's titles to also be highlighted with nav-links under it

Example: When a user is on *warum* section on the page then both warum link under the dropdown menu and Homepages section text should be highlighted.

Same for the other dropdown menu. When a user is on *glassAndBuildingCleaningPage* section on the page then both *glassAndBuildingCleaningPage and Subpages link* should be highlighted.

```html
<nav id="navbarMain" class=" navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light col px-md-3 px-sm-1 ">
  <div class="container-fluid px-md-5 px-sm-0 mainlogo ">
    <a class="navbar-brand " href=""><img class="img-fluid " src="" alt="" style="max-width:300px;"></a><button class="navbar-toggler navbar-dark" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false"
      aria-label="Toggle navigation"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon "></span></button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav justify-content-end ">
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#dashboard">Dashboard</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item my-auto px-xl-3 px-ld-1 "><a class="nav-link active hometag" aria-current="page" href="/#hero">Home</a></li>
        <li id="warumdrop" class="nav-item px-xl-3 px-lg-1 my-auto dropdown"><a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle " href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Homepages section</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu " aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/#warum">warum</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/#whyus">why us</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/#feedback">feedback</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item px-xl-3 px-lg-1 my-auto dropdown "><a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle " href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Subpages link</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu " aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>requirements/glassAndBuildingCleaningPage">glassAndBuildingCleaningPage</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>requirements/janitorialPage">janitorialPage</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>requirements/chemicalCleaningPage">Cleaning</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>requirements/theCurtainPage">curtain</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item px-xl-3 px-lg-1 my-auto "><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>requirements/contactPage" class="nav-link ">contact</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item px-xl-3 px-lg-1 my-auto "><a style="color:#D70143;" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>requirements/vacanciesPage" class="nav-link joblink">Jobpage</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a style="color:#D70143;" href="'. base_url() .'requirements/logout" class="nav-link ">Logout</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item "><a href="#" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#loginmodal" style="color:#032A66; font-size:25px; width:auto;" class=" loginatag nav-link "><i class="bi bi-box-arrow-in-right"></i></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks you guys for pointing out my mistake have formated question accordingly

Comment: Much better, except for the quote and bold button abuse. :P